# Can't play a video in Html

Tags: html, video

I can play a video `my.mp4` by using

```
<video src="my.mp4" width="720" height="340" poster="mine.jpg" onclick="this.play();"/></video>
```

and Now I cut a video from my.mp4 by using `MediaCope` application and the output of splitter video as `my1.mp4` and I can play my1.mp4 in player. But I cant play this video in HTML. I can't find the reason for it. Any suggestion for fix my problem

Comment: What is the result of `readyState`, `networkState` and `error.code` (if `error` is not `null`) attributes of the `video` element ?

Comment: I didn't get any error.. I can hear a audio but video is not shown

Comment: where are you trying to play it back? Chrome, Firefox, Safari? PC, Mac, iPad, Android? Do you have a sample so we can look at the encoding?

Comment: @Offbeatmammal In chrome.. I can hear a audio but video is in black view

Answer (score 0):

You should try using iframe, hopefully this will solve your problem.

```html
 <iframe width="600" height="600"
src="http://www.cricingif.com/Ball/201004">
</iframe>
```